# How to bind IDictionary property with Ninject?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Inject]
    public IDictionary<string, IMyInterface> MyDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

I have several implementations of the `IMyInterface` interface that have their own dependencies injected. Each implementation should have a different key.

How do I bind such a property using Ninject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is a fixed list. The easiest way would be with a provider:

```
    public class MyProvider :  IProvider
    {
        public object Create(IContext context)
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, IMyInterface>{
               {"alpha", context.Kernel.Get<ImpClassOne>()},
               {"beta", context.Kernel.Get<ImplClassTwo>()}
            }
        }

        public Type Type
        {
            get { return typeof(IDictionary<string, IMyInterface>); }
        }
    }
```

You can register the provider to your kernel like:

```
   kernel.Bind<IDictionary<string, IMyInterface>>().ToProvider<MyProvider>();
```

and then the [Inject] for the property will  use the provider to create the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, still learning Ninject and didn't know about providers yet.

Answer (score 3):

In case the key can somehow be retrieved/generated/calculated from `IMyInterface` e.g. from a Name property then there is an easy solution.

```
public class DictionaryProvider : Provider<IDictionary<string, IMyInterface>>
{
    private IEmumerable<IMyInterface> instances;
    public DictionaryProvider(IEmumerable<IMyInterface> instances>)
    {
        this.instances = instances;
    }

    protected override IDictionary<string, IMyInterface> CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        return this.instances.ToDictionary(i => i.Name);
    }
}
```

Otherwise ryber's solution is probably the easiest way to go.